# if slug already exist in table how to add number after slug (like ... php-slug-1)

Tags: php, mysql, url, slug

how to add number if same slug already exist in database

```
   <?php 

           if ($title == "" || $cat == "" || $body == "" || $author == "" ) {
            echo "<span class='error'>Field must not be empty !! </span>";
        } else{
                
            $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_post( title, slug, cat, body, tags, author,viewname, userid, userrole) VALUES( '$title', '$slug', '$cat', '$body', '$tags', '$author', '$viewname', '$userid', '$userrole' )";
            $inserted_rows = $db->insert($query);
            if ($inserted_rows) {
               echo "<span class='success'>Post Inserted Successfully.
               </span>";
           }else {
               echo "<span class='error'>Post Not Inserted !</span>";
           }
       }

   }
   ?>
```

please help about my problem. I am new learner php

Answer (score 0):

Why not make `title` unique in your database and then base the slug on the title, like so:

```
function slugify ($title){
        return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $title), '-'));
    }

$slug = slugify($title);
```

What the function does is basically replacing every uppercase to lowercase and removing illegal chars. For example `Hello World!` becomes `hello-world`.

Since the probabilty for multiple titles with the same name is low, and also having the unique attribute on the database column, you will most likely not end up with any duplicate slugs.

It is in my opinion also a cleaner solution than to have `hello-world`, `hello-world-1`, `hello-world-2`, etc.

[see here how to make a column unique in your database](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/)

Comment: this is not totally wrong but will fail in case where different strings have same slug.